# PLT Latex with variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, latex

I'm trying to create a function in python which creates plot x^a. I want to have title LaTex x^a, where a takes the passed value. I have the following for the function which creates x^2 plot:

```
a = r'{x^2}'
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title(f"ƒ(x)= {'$%s$' %a}")
```

but I have no idea how I can implement to it .format(a) so that value of a becomes a degree of x in LaTex plot title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this,

```
a = r'$x^{}$'.format(pw)
```